# Infinite loop with React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to figure out how to resolve an infinite loop issue.

FLOW: I have a state hook `setUserData` that I am passing to `HomePage`. From `HomePage` I am calling API to retrieve data and then set it in the `App` component.

Now when data is set and I click back button, then it into an infinite loop because `userData` is already set.

What can I do to fix it ?

CODE OF INTEREST:

```
                 {userData ?
                  <Redirect push
                    to={{
                      pathname: "/user",
                      search: `username=${userData.data.login}`
                    }}
                  />
                  :
                  <Homepage setUserData={setUserData} />}
```

---

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Homepage from "./components/Homepage";
import ResultsPage from "./components/ResultsPage";
import Footer from "./components/Footer"
import { HashRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            {userData ?
              <Redirect push
                to={{
                  pathname: "/user",
                  search: `username=${userData.data.login}`
                }}
              />
              :
              <Homepage setUserData={setUserData} />}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/user">
            <ResultsPage userData={userData} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
      {/* <Footer /> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: your logic is incorrect.so what feature would u want to achieved?

Comment: I want to take data coming from child component (HomePage) and pass it to another component (ResultsPage). But I also understand that it is causing an infinite loop. I am wondering if there is a way to fix it while keeping the above described flow.

Comment: u can make the redirect step into your HomePage file

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. It is going to HomePage if userdata is not fetched.

Comment: u mean when u get `userData ` u can't go `Homepage` right? or what's mean of infinite loop ?

Comment: Correct. When userData is not null, then I cannot go to HomePage because of the condition above. Maybe there is a way to reset userData when going backwards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Base URL points to HomePage. When search is done on HomePage, data is passed to ResultsPage. (This is happening currently). Issue is that once userData is populated then clicking back redirects to ResultPage again. I need to be able to come back to HomePage when user clicks back button on home browser (Even if data is already loaded).

if u want achieved it, the better way is handle redirect in your homepage file

assume that
HomePage.jsx

```
import { useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

const HomePage = (props)=>{
  const { setUserData } = props
  ....
  const history = useHistory()
  const handleClick = ()=>{
    const data = HTTP.get('api')
    setUserData(data)
    history.push(`/user?username=${data}`)
  }
  ...
  return (
   ...
   <button onClick={handleClick} >BUTTON</button>
   ...
 
  )

}
```

App.jsx

```
function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Homepage setUserData={setUserData} />}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/user">
            <ResultsPage userData={userData} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
      {/* <Footer /> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This will not work because when I set hasGetData to true then I will not be able to go to ResultsPage.

Comment: @testdummy so what feature would you want to achieve?

Comment: Base URL points to HomePage. When search is done on HomePage, data is passed to ResultsPage. (This is happening currently). Issue is that once userData is populated then clicking back redirects to ResultPage again. I need to be able to come back to HomePage when user clicks back button on home browser (Even if data is already loaded).

Comment: To give you an analogy: Think of it like logging out of facebook with the back button (instead of clicking logout).